# Why does no antitoxin for botulinum type H exist yet?

Tags: toxicity, proteins

Antitoxins against the botulinum toxins type A–G produced by *Clostridium botulinum* are known. Why does none exist against the type H botulinum toxin yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The premise of this question is based upon outdated information.

According to [Study: Novel botulinum toxin less dangerous than thought](http://www.cidrap.umn.edu/news-perspective/2015/06/study-novel-botulinum-toxin-less-dangerous-thought)

> Researchers from the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) and the University of Wisconsin (UW), writing in the Journal of Infectious Diseases (JID), said it turns out that the novel toxin can be blocked by available antitoxins after all. That suggests that it isn't really a novel toxin, the authors said

(**Attention grammar police: The above is an exact quote from the linked reference.  If you feel the compulsion to keep editing this again and again, please do it in a way that makes clear it is no longer an exact quote.**)